# emacs still makes backup files even after I tell it not to

Tags: auto-save

(I did restart emacs after adding config)
I'm on GNU Emacs 28.0.50 (build 1, aarch64-apple-darwin20.5.0) of 2021-06-07
My config:

```
(setq make-backup-files nil)

;disable backup
(setq backup-inhibited t)
;disable auto save
(setq auto-save-default nil)
```

What could be going on?
[image]

Comment: Why a screenshot? And even worse why an animated GIF? It's hard enough to read things that are too small but at least stay still.

Comment: sorry im weird like that

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a misunderstanding of the file in question, and is unlikely to be helpful for future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be highlighting a lock file, not a backup file.

Comment: thanks,
to prevent an expensive webpacker recompilation, I will do `(setq create-lockfiles nil)`